# Python member variable as parameter

Tags: python, function, class, variables, default-value

I have a class `A` with a member function `a` and a parameter `p` with a default value. I want this default value to be the member variable of the class.

```
class A:
   def a(self, p = self.b):
       print p
```

However it crashed with the information:

```
<ipython-input-2-a0639d7525d3> in A()
      1 class A:
----> 2     def a(self, p = self.b):
      3         print p
      4

NameError: name 'self' is not defined
```

I want to know whether I can pass a member variable as a default parameter to the member function?

Answer (score 3):

One option would be to set the default `p` value as `None` and check its value in the method itself:

```
class A:
    def __init__(self, b):
        self.b = b

    def a(self, p=None):
        if p is None:
            p = self.b
        print(p)
```

Demo:

```
In [1]: class A:
    ...:     def __init__(self, b):
    ...:         self.b = b
    ...: 
    ...:     def a(self, p=None):
    ...:         if p is None:
    ...:             p = self.b
    ...:         print(p)
    ...:         

In [2]: a = A(10)

In [3]: a.a()
10

In [4]: a.a(12)
12
```

Comment: I have several parameters and I don't want to judge them one by one. Can this be wraped into a function? one problem is that if they are warped into a function, the value variable can not be set in a function.

Comment: @maple okay, yeah, that does not scale that good. Do you want all the method arguments have the same `self.b` default value? Thanks.

Comment: I want they have different default value and can be set in the funciton.